# Two filters - adding a query string not working?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 1.0 project.

The following code sets the filter `categoryTitle` for the controller.

**app.js**

```
  .state('tab.events', {
    url: '/events/:categoryTitle',
    views: {
      'tab-events': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-events.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

**controllers.js**

```
  .controller('EventsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, EventService) {
    var category = $stateParams.categoryTitle;
    // var period = $stateParams.period;
    var events = EventService.query({ category: category, period: period });
    events.$promise.then(function (response) {
      $scope.events = response;
      $scope.category = category;
      // $scope.period = period;
    });
  })
```

So the url http://localhost:8100/#/tab/events/Music will filter the page to show the category of Music only. Now I need to add another filter `period`. So I  changed the `app.js` to the following and uncommented the two lines in the `controller.js`

```
  .state('tab.events', {
    url: '/events/:categoryTitle?p=:period', // Added "?p=:period"
    views: {
      'tab-events': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-events.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

However, http://localhost:8100/#/tab/events/Music?p=weekend always gets `undefined` in the controller line `var period = $stateParams.period;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are monitoring the wrong parameter. In your example the second parameter (the one you are setting in the query string would be `p` and not `period`.

Check the example [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) explaining how the `$stateParams` service works

Example:

```
// you navigated your browser to:
'/users/123/details/default/0?from=there&to=here'

// Your $stateParams object would be
{ id:'123', type:'default', repeat:'0', from:'there', to:'here' }
```

From what you can see in the example the `$stateParams` object will return an object containing both parameters defined as `:parameter` or the ones defined as query string parameter

Comment: Thanks, change `period` to `p` works. However, now I have a new issue. I created the following links in the code `<a class="tab-item" ui-sref="tab.events({p:Weekend})">
                Weekend
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="tab.events({p:All})">
                All
            </a>`. But clicking these links don't do anything in the browser?

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with being what looks like a nested state? Is tab.events a child of a tab state? Would have to dig deeper for that particular problem

Comment: These links are added to the same page. I want clicking these links to add or update the query string parameter p.

Comment: Might the :period be causing some sort of issues? Have you tried declaring the url without it? Something like url: ‘events/:categoryTitle?p’